# How to project a 3D sphere function in 2D?

Tags: python, optimization, graph, 3d

I have this code to draw a graph of the 3D sphere function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-5.12,5.12, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5.12,5.12, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(t, y)
Z = X ** 2 + Y ** 2
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap ='viridis', edgecolor ='c')
ax.set_title('3D Sphere Function')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I want to show an array of points in the graph, but it wouldn't be very visible. I want to project the same sphere, but on a flat 2D surface, with the third dimension being projected as colors, something like this:[image]

How could I plot this in python?

Comment: I think you are looking for `plt.imshow`? Just provide correct `extent` parameter

Comment: Your sphere equation is wrong. What you've shown is a paraboloid.